# Testing the pyomo optimization model

Tags: optimization, pyomo

I have a resource scheduling optimization model in Pyomo with **3 constraints** and an **objective**. The model runs well for the minimization and maximization objectives.

```
Constraint1: Each job is assigned to some machine.
Constraint2: Demand job <= Capacity of the machine.
Constraint3: Each job must be assigned to almost 1 machine.
Objective: MIN(Jobs placement cost on different machines)
```

*Now, I want to write a function that varifies my pyomo model's result is "as" expected*.  I mean the function will confirm that my model validates all the constraints before the results.
Looking for some directions

Comment: Scan each constraint, and replace the variables by their value. And check that the constraint is satisfied indeed.

Comment: @Kuifje I appreciate your prompt response. Actually, I am interested in testing my model with a help of a separate test function.

Comment: I presume you are trying to verify that you modeled the problem correctly (as opposed to verifying that the solver did not make a mistake). You just have to write Python code that reads the solution and checks all the requirements.

Comment: Yeah @prubin you are right. I am looking for a function that verifies my model. I am new to Pyomo and need a hint for this. Regards

Comment: What you need is a plain python function, unrelated to Pyomo. You use Pyomo to solve the model and fetch the solution (into a local variable or variables), then pass those variables to a pure python function (no Pyomo involved) that checks that all requirements are met.

Comment: As suggested by @prubin, implement a separate Python "checking" function. This function takes as input the mathematical solution provided by the solver. In this function, you check the feasibility of each constraint and compute the value of the objective function by implementing constraints and objectives on your business objects (jobs, machines) and not on variables of your mathematical model. This kind of check is critical for any business optimization project/code. Because a mathematical model which is not double-checked is by experience 99%-chance errorful.